# IOS Key needed for Phonegap

Tags: ios, certificate, phonegap

I am designing an App with phonegap and have no Idea about Macs neither do I own one. I need to develop an IOS App and it requires a certificate. I was wondering if there are websites that sell these keys or something or how to generate one without magically turning my PC to a Mac. It'll be of so much help.

Answer (score 0):

It could be best if you run OSX on a  Virtual Machine. You can find them on youtube just search "Sierra Windows". The reason why I recommend this is because there are other required files besides the certificate. There are the icons and logos that you'll need to put on XCode before it can actually be built and send to https://itunesconnect.apple.com/.

Comment: Thanks @gentlyawesome